# Can an Aberrant Mind and Clockwork Soul Sorcerer replace two spells at level up?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, spellcasting, sorcerer

All sorcerers are allowed to replace one spell they known when they level up:

> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the Sorcerer Spells you know and replace it with another spell from the Sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have Spell Slots.

Moreover, the Clockwork Magic feature let the Clockwork Soul Sorcerer replace one of their spell known at level up:

> Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level. The new spell must be an abjuration or a transmutation spell from the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list.

Same for the Psionic Spells feature of the Aberrant Mind Sorcerer:

> Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level. The new spell must be a divination or an enchantment spell from the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list.

My question: can the Clockwork Soul Sorcerer and the Aberrant Mind Sorcerer swap two of their spells at level up, as long as one is from their "normal" list and one is from their origin?

Or, do these Sorcerers have to pick to either replace a single one of their Sorcerer spells using the general rule, or replace a single of their origin list using the special Clockwork Magic / Psionic Spells rules?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### The Spellcasting feature and the Psionic Spells/Clockwork Magic features are entirely different features.

All sorcerers have the Spellcasting feature, part of which says:

> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the sorcerer spells you know and replace it with another spell from the sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

So *any* sorcerer has this feature and may use it at level up.

The Aberrant Mind and Clockwork sorcerers have an *additional* feature that allows them to replace an *additional* spell at level up, with some restrictions. The Aberrant Mind's Psionic Spells feature says:

> Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level. The new spell must be a divination or an enchantment spell from the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list.

So an Aberrant Mind sorcerer *has both of these features*, so it may use *both of these features* at level up, allowing them to replace two spells. The Clockwork Soul sorcerer's Clockwork Magic feature works similarly, also allowing them to replace *two* spells at level up - one with the generic sorcerer's Spellcasting feature, and one with Clockwork Magic.

Comment: Whilst that is obvious, the real question OP should have been asking is whether you can replace one of the spells gained from the Psionic Spells feature immediately when you gain it at level 1. After all, "whenever you gain a sorcerer level" is technically a valid description for level 1 too, is it not? ;)